# file transfer using RMI

Tags: java, rmi

How to do the file transfer using RMI in java?

Comment: You don't. RMI is violently unsuitable for this.

Answer (score 8):

You need to read chunks of the file, send them over the wire via an RMI call, and then write them on the other side.

This library may help: http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/